# In Vue3, How can I invoke method exposed by child component before child component being mounted?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

For example, I want to call *expand* method as soon as the tree component is created. if I use template ref, it will be undefined when I try to access the child component in the setup function. if I use the nextTick function, the tree component will first be unexpanded when shows up, and expanded after a flash.

So, is there any way to call the exposed method after the child component is created, but before mounted?

Comment: You can't. Please, explain your case further, this is XY problem that's supposed to be solved in another way. It's unknown why you insist on it being a method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.